# android emultater always shows a blank black screen when i run my app

Tags: android

My android emulator was working fine. Then the next day when I started king on my app the emulater showed a blank black screen. I tried to run another app I was working on same thing.  Tried to create a new app and emulator same thing.

Comment: Probably you need to power it on on the top right power button or hit CTRL + P

Answer (score 0):

If the XML file is still showing you a view of what should be there I'd say its an issue with the emulator your using, try the nexus 5X and let me know how you get on.

Alternativly you can use your own phone by enabling developer mode turning on usb debuging and plug it in to your computer to run the app off of.

Would have put this as a comment but dont have enough cred :P hope it helps.

Comment: yes on the ide the xml file shows me what I should see.  Also tried old projects and creating a fresh one, all did same thing

Answer (score -1):

remove emulator from avd manager and make a new one